# Passing a function call as a parameter to insert statement - possible issues

Tags: plsql

While looking through some sql code I found a function call passed as a parameter to an insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO Table1(field1, field2)VALUES('myvalue', myfunction('test'));
```

are there any possible issues with using that as opposed to declaring a variable, assigning to it the return valu of the function and then passing in that variable to an insert?

Comment: You don't show what the function signature looks like or what is does, but I don't see why there would be any issue using it as you show.

Comment: A separate variable declaration just to avoid inlining something like `upper(name)` seems more verbose and less efficient than doing it the straightforward way, unless the same computation is needed in multiple places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no issue with this. The result of the function will be calculated and passed in. It's a convenient way of doing:

```
result := myfunction('test');
INSERT INTO Table1(field1, field2)VALUES('myvalue', result);
```